# Setting up Hadoop on a RHEL machine with a security policy

Tags: hadoop, ssh, redhat, rhel

I have been playing around with a Hadoop installation on CentOS for a while but today when I shifted to RHEL I got pesky password prompts when trying to start the **pseudo-distributed cluster**. After hours of poking around I finally managed to get rid of them by removing the security policy I had selected during installation of RHEL. 
Looks like some aspect of the security policy was not letting me set up password less SSH to allow the different servers to communicate.

Going forward I would like to be able to run a cluster on machines with security policy enabled. What are the changes that I need to make, or where should I start looking into, to get the right set of network configurations?

Answer (score 1):

> I got pesky password prompts when trying to start the pseudo-distributed cluster

That's a sign you did not correctly establish a **passwordless** SSH keypair. Perhaps you did type a password when you generated the key? Or you didn't add it correctly into the authorized keys file for an SSH session.

This should not prompt for a password

```
$ ssh localhost
```

And if it does, generate keys again without a password

```
$ ssh-keygen -t rsa -P '' -f ~/.ssh/id_rsa
$ cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
$ chmod 0600 ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

Also, RHEL systems need SELinux disabled. I believe Cloudera and Hortonworks install guides also have you turning the firewall off

If you want a secure cluster, you would install and configure MIT Kerberos or Active Directory

Comment: Thanks! I did take care of the points you mention (courtesy stack overflow answers) but to no avail. Thanks for the Kerberos mention. Checking that out now.

Comment: https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.3/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/SecureMode.html